# Problem serving Flask based applications with uWSGI and Nginx and Tensorflow on CentOS 7

Tags: tensorflow, nginx, flask, centos, uwsgi

I'm serving an application with Tensorflow. Now I need to serve this flask based application with Ngnix. I used this [document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7#prerequisites) on Digitalocean.

Direct serving application with uWSGI is okay but as soon as the service is transferred to Nginx , I get an internal service error (500).

service works fine without Tensorflow and Keras library so I'm pretty sure server config is fine.

myproject.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi
    
master = true
processes = 5
    
socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target
    
[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank a lot. Also sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was tried to change **.ini** file but that was not work for me. Somethings like to add `cheaper = 0` or change `processes = 1` and `master = false`. but somebody told me use [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) instead of `uWSGI` and that's work.

And that was so easy to switch from uWSGI to Gunicorn. Based on [this document on Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7) you just need to change

1. `(/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service)` this file on line 10 (`ExecStart` part)
2. `(/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)` this file in `location` part

** If you have not configured the server yet, just use [this paper](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7)

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English.